# Check if date is exists among the dates then add extra one day to that date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to add the days(for example 3 days) to the given date. Before adding days we can check the holidays which are already configured in one table. 
  Here is my sample code. But i am unable to achieve it.

```
declare @HolidaysList NVARCHAR(250) = '2014-06-29,2014-07-02,2014-07-18,2014-07-30,2014-10-26'
DECLARE @RDATE DATE = '2014-06-28' 
declare @addDays int = 3
declare @count int = 0

while(@count < @addDays)
    BEGIN
        set @RDATE = DATEADD(DAY,1,@RDATE)
        --print '1  ' +cast( @RDATE as nvarchar(100))
        if exists(SELECT ITEM FROM fnSplit(@HolidaysList,',') WHERE item = @RDATE)
            begin
                SELECT @RDATE= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,1,@RDATE),101)
                PRINT 'if '+ CAST( @HRDATE AS NVARCHAR(100))
            end

        set @count = @count+1

    END
PRINT @RDATE
```

Here **fnSplit** is a function which returns a table.
In the above script i have to add 3 days to **@RDate**. Before adding i have to check holidays list i.e in **@HolidaysList**. If holiday is come then we can add extra date.

in the above script the output is: **2014-08-03** because 29th is holiday and 2nd is also holiday. so output will be 2014-08-03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without loops:

```
DECLARE @Holidays TABLE (Item DATE);
INSERT @Holidays 
VALUES ('2014-06-29'),('2014-07-02'),('2014-07-18'),('2014-07-30'),('2014-10-26');

DECLARE @RDATE DATE = '2014-06-28',
        @addDays INT = 3;

WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.Date)
    FROM    (   SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id), @RDATE)
                FROM    sys.all_objects
            ) AS d (Date)
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    @Holidays AS h
                WHERE   h.Item = d.Date
            )
)
SELECT  Date
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNumber = @addDays;
```

The principal is this part:

```
SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id), @RDATE)
FROM    sys.all_objects
```

Will just generate a list of dates onwards from your starting date. You then exclude all holidays from this list using `NOT EXISTS`, and add a rank to all these days using ROW_NUMBER(). It is then just a case of selecting the date with the required rank.

Comment: Great answer GarethD.. Thank you. I have solved it another way but could tell me which one is more efficient?

Comment: SQL is not really designed for loops, so avoiding them wherever possible is advisable. But you'd need to test both if you wanted to find out for sure which is more efficient for your exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @HolidaysList NVARCHAR(250) = '2014-06-29,2014-06-30,2014-07-01,2014-07-30,2014-07-18,2014-10-26'
DECLARE @RDATE DATE = '2014-06-28'
declare @addDays int = 3
declare @count int = 0
DECLARE @EXISTS int = 0

while(@count < @addDays)
    BEGIN
        set @RDATE = DATEADD(DAY,1,@RDATE)
        if exists(SELECT ITEM FROM fnSplit(@HolidaysList,',') WHERE item = @RDATE)
             set @EXISTS = @EXISTS+1             
        set @count = @count+1       
    END
if(@EXISTS is not null)
    set @RDATE = DATEADD(DAY,@EXISTS,@RDATE)
print @RDATE
```